# Access Method in a hasManyThorugh

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 4 tables,

props, listing, offers, contact

props has many listing, listing belongs to props

> public function listings()
>       {
>           return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Listing\Listing');
>       }

offer belongs to listing,

```
public function property()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Property\Property')->with('owners');
}
```

then
offer belongsToMany contact trough offer_contact table

```
public function buyers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Contact::class, 'offer_contact', 'offer_id', 'contact_id')->with('primary_email');
}
```

My question is, how to access buyers()?

Something like $props->buyers()

In props model, what I did is

```
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Offer\Offer', 'App\Models\Listing\Listing');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. You may use nested iterations to get properties, listings belongs to each property, offers belongs to each listing and then customers belonging with the offer.

Alternatively, you may use the raw query to get the desired result using `DB::statement();`

Answer (score 0):

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class Property extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function buyers() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Contact::class, [Listing::class, Offer::class, 'offer_contact']);
    }
}
```